# @OneToMany with @JoinFormula using polymorphism and generic

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I have the following use case:

- Parents contain Children and ParentTags.
- Children contain ChildrenTags and their Parent node.
- Both ParentTags and ChildrenTags are Tags with T being Parent or Child.

Now I want a derived field in Parent that map all tags relative to this parent or to one of its children.
The SQL query is straightforward but I can't make it work by annotating a given property.
Note that the @ManyToOne mapping works like a charm in order to find the Parent owner of a tag, cf my code below (this is a @OneToMany relation, Tag is maybe not the best name I could find for this example).

#### Parent.class

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<ParentTag> tags;

    // Does not work!
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Tag<?>> allTags;

}
```

#### Child.class

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Child {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "child")
    private List<ChildTag> tags;

}
```

#### Tag.class

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Tag<T> {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    protected String value;

    @NotAudited // otherwise ClassCastException
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(
                value = "CASE WHEN parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN parent_id WHEN child_id IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT child.parent_id FROM Child child WHERE child.id = child_id) end",
                referencedColumnName="id"))
    })
    private Parent owner;

    public abstract T getNode();

}
```

#### ChildTag.class

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class ChildTag extends Tag<Child> {

    @ManyToOne
    private Child child;

    @Override
    public Child getNode() {
        return child;
    }

}
```

#### ParentTag.class

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class ParentTag extends Tag<Parent> {

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    @Override
    public Parent getNode() {
        return parent;
    }

}
```

I'd like to find a way to load allTags by a given query or formula.
The inverse mapping @ManyToOne works (as long as owner is not audited, it was hard to find that bug).

I already tried the following solutions without success:

#### @JoinFormula

```
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(
                value = "CASE WHEN parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN parent_id WHEN child_id IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT child.parent_id FROM Child child WHERE child.id = child_id) end",
                referencedColumnName="id"))
    })
    private List<Tag<?>> allTags;
```

I get a ClassCastException, Formula cannot be cast into a Column

#### @Loader

```
@Entity
@Audited
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "loadAllTags",
    query = "SELECT * FROM Tag tag WHERE "
        + "(tag.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND tag.parent_id = :id) OR "
        + "(tag.child_id IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Child child WHERE child.id = tag.child_id AND child.parent_id = :id))")
public class Parent {    
    ...
    @Loader(namedQuery = "loadAllTags")
    private List<Tag<?>> allTags;
}
```

No exception, actually when debugging I can see that the loader find all appropriate tags, but does not initialize the collection with them.
I also tried to put the query in a hbm configuration file, as I understood that @Loader and @NamedNativeQuery do not get along well, but without success (maybe I did something wrong here). However I'd rather implement a solution without configuration file.

I could add another column (owner_id) but if I can find a way to solve that problem without changing the model, it would be better.

I don't know if generics have something to do with it. In addition my entities are audited and indexed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!